# Redirect current IO device for 3rd party routine interaction

Tags: windows, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I have many vendor supplied M-Code routines as part of a much larger product that use `READ` and `WRITE` directly to interact with the current device. I can't change that code. I want to wrap some of those routines in a system where I can supply input and capture output interactively.

Currently, this is implemented by opening a TCP connection to a remote host and making that the current device. `READ` and `WRITE` are indeed connected to the socket. This is fairly inconvenient though as it requires a separate service that listens on a TCP socket be set up and coordinate with the local job to make the whole process work. I also have to turn off nagle and skip buffering or the connection becomes latency driven or stalls. (e.g. TCP OPEN option `/SEN=1` aka `+Q`). Unfortunately, that results in many 1 byte TCP segments and is also very inefficient.

I would much rather drive the whole interaction through a single process. Ideally, I could have calls to `READ`, `WRITE` and the other functions that operate on the current device trigger some M-Code or callbacks in the [Caché Callin C interface](http://docs.intersystems.com/documentation/cache/20102/pdfs/GCIO.pdf) or a user extension module to provide the required functions on the back end. That way, I can manage IO on my own terms without needing interprocess coordination. I haven't been able to find an entry point to set that up though.

Is there such a thing as a user-defined device in Caché?

For UNIX hosts, there is a way to use an existing file descriptor as a device, which could be useful, but that doesn't seem to be implemented on Windows.

One thing I have considered is to create a new process, have Windows redirect `STDIN` and `STDOUT` with [SetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244(v=vs.85).aspx) to pipes I control from within the same process, use Callin to connect to Caché and let it use the default device which is supposed to be `STDIN` and `STDOUT`. Anyone know if that would actually work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caché actually supports arbitrary IO redirection. This is possible with an undocumented feature. Not recommended, but unlikely to change.

Annotated code is below. In this example, I choose to redirect the IO to a %Stream.GlobalBinary - you can whatever you like with it. The key is the specific names of the labels - you can specify a different routine with the use $io:: call, and specify those labels elsewhere.

```
//The ProcedureBlock = 0 is important
//  it allows for calling of labels within the ClassMethod
ClassMethod testIORedirection() [ ProcedureBlock = 0 ]
{
    //Create a stream that we will redirect to
    set myStream = ##class(%Stream.GlobalBinary).%New()

    //Redirect IO to the current routine - makes use of the labels defined below
    use $io::("^"_$ZNAME)

    //Enable redirection
    do ##class(%Device).ReDirectIO(1)

    //Any write statements here will be redirected to the labels defined below
    write "Here is a string", !, !
    write "Here is something else", !

    //Disable redirection
    do ##class(%Device).ReDirectIO(0)

    //Print out the stream, to prove that it worked
    write "Now printing the string:", !
    write myStream.Read()


    //Labels that allow for IO redirection
    //Read Character - we don't care about reading
rchr(c)      quit
    //Read a string - we don't care about reading
rstr(sz,to)  quit
    //Write a character - call the output label
wchr(s)      do output($char(s))  quit
    //Write a form feed - call the output label
wff()        do output($char(12))  quit
    //Write a newline - call the output label
wnl()        do output($char(13,10))  quit
    //Write a string - call the output label
wstr(s)      do output(s)  quit
    //Write a tab - call the output label
wtab(s)      do output($char(9))  quit
    //Output label - this is where you would handle what you actually want to do.
    //  in our case, we want to write to myStream
output(s)    do myStream.Write(s)  quit
}
```